# How to set a TextBox for password input in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to set a TextBox for password input in WinForms? Also I want to show "Capslock is ON" popup if capslock is on.

I want something like

`<input type="password" />` in HTML.

Answer (score 76):

The best way to solve your problem is to set the `UseSystemPasswordChar` property to true. Then, the Caps-lock message is shown when the user enters the field and the Caps-Lock is on (at least for Vista and Windows 7).

Another alternative is to set the  `PasswordChar` property to a character value (* for example). This also triggers the automatic Caps-Lock handling.

Comment: 'UseSystemPasswordChar' also enable the feature which clear the text (if something in it) once you hit tab button and get the focus on the password control, as Windows accustomed us. It behavior sometime happens when you failed to logged once.

Comment: Thanks for this! My **favorite one!**

Answer (score 28):

**To set a text box for password input:**

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
```

you can also change this property in design time by editing properties of the text box.

**To show if "Capslock is ON":**

```
using System;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
//...
if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock)) {  
    MessageBox.Show("The Caps Lock key is ON.");  
}
```

Comment: Instead of messagebox isn't it possible to get that nice yellow colored popup. which we generally get in system tray when our antivirus is out of date or firewall is tuned off. But I want that to be displayed for text box. It is shown for Google Talk.

Comment: You can set a pop-up for control, see example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx

Comment: If the `PasswordChar` or the `UseSystemPasswordChar` is used - at least on Windows 7 and Vista - the Caps-Lock is handled automatically if the field receives the focus.

Answer (score 20):

To make `PasswordChar` use the ● character instead:

`passwordTextBox.PasswordChar = '\u25CF';`

Comment: ...in the designer.cs.  ● in the properties. +1.

Answer (score 14):

Just set the [TextBox.PasswordChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx) property to '*'.

Answer (score 6):

Just set the property of textbox that is 
     PasswordChar and set the **`*`** as a property
of textbox. That will work for password.

```
  passwordtextbox.PasswordChar = '*';
```

where `passwordtextbox` is the text box name.

Answer (score 5):

```
private void cbShowHide_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbShowHide.Checked)
    {
        txtPin.UseSystemPasswordChar = PasswordPropertyTextAttribute.No.Password;
    }
    else
    {
        //Hides Textbox password
        txtPin.UseSystemPasswordChar = PasswordPropertyTextAttribute.Yes.Password;
    }
}
```

Copy this code to show and hide your textbox using a checkbox

Answer (score 2):

you can use like these "txtpassword.PasswordChar = '•';"

the use location is ...

```
 namespace Library_Management_System
    {
        public partial class Login : Form
        {
            public Login()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                txtpassword.PasswordChar = '•';
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the perfect answer:

1. double click on The password TextBox.
2. write your textbox name like textbox2.
3. write PasswordChar = '*';.
4. I prefer going to windows character map and find a perfect hide like ●.

   ```
   example:TextBox2.PasswordChar = '●';
   ```

Answer (score 1):

it's easy, look:

1. Create `TextBox` control
2. Click once on it in the form constructor (Open its properties)
3. Find the category called `Behavior`
4. Here you can find 2 properties: `PasswordChar` and `UseSystemPasswordChar`

Here you have 2 ways:

1. Set the `UseSystemPasswordChar` to `True`. Symbols in your textbox will probably set to * or another system password char (depending you what system you use)
2. Set you own char with `PasswordChar`.
   For example you can put char like that: ●