# C# Login page. SQL Server " sda.Fill(dt); " ERROR

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcmmCcMs8yU). It basically teaches me how to create my own login page using SQL Server.

So after following exactly what he did, when I click the submit button I have an error highlighting `sda.Fill(dt);`. I am pretty new to SQL Server, please advise!

My code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Glenntdy\Documents\GlennTeoDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");        

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Table where Username='"+txtName.Text + "' and Password = '" +txtPassword.Text + "'",con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

sda.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
{
    this.Hide();

    Main ss = new Main();
    ss.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please double check your Username and password");
}
```

Picture of error:

[image]

Comment: Can you  please show us `InnerException`, if one exists?

Comment: Your SQL seems to be incorrect...what is the name of the table you want to query the data from?

Comment: For your password text problem.., Set a value to your `TextBox1.PasswordChar` property. If you want to show asterisk(*), set it as
`TextBox1.PasswordChar = '*';`
See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555984/how-to-set-a-text-box-for-inputing-password-in-winforms)

Comment: Yup, thanks Sohaiby. It worked.

Comment: Last question here, since I am going to pass this project up to my teacher the database path will not exist. Any idea how to fix this? Like placing the database in the same folder as my program? Do I need to change anything or look out for anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table is a reserved keyword and should be surrounded by braces like `[Table]`. Additionally it is **not** recommended to construct your query the way you do, because of SqlInjection. Read more on [SqlParameters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter). One more thing.. you should close the SqlConnection after use.

Comment: IIRC SQLInjection is an attack? I will be sure to take note of this! Thankfully this project is just a school with no marks given for security and you're right! Tabe is reserved and should not have been used. I have edit it already!

Comment: Just imagine the user enters `' OR 1=1 --` as password? Read more about [SqlInjections](http://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection) here...

Comment: @MrTeo Use SqlCommand.Parameters Property in order to be safe from SQL Injection threat. It's easy, no rocket science. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)
for details.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys! I will be sure to look out for it in the future. All of you have been really helpful!

Comment: You might consider marking the helpful answers.. :-)

Comment: Yup,sure. sadly I cannot thumb it up as I do not have enough reputation. Last question here, since I am going to pass this project up to my teacher the database path will not exist. Any idea how to fix this? Like placing the database in the same folder as my program? Do I need to change anything or look out for anything?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY0bk.png)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection (@"Data SOURCE=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\itmaint\source\repos\database\database\G-data.mdf;Integrated Se[a.][2]curity=True;Connection Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        string query ="Select * From Login Where Username='" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "' and Password ='" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            Form2 ss = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            ss.Show();
        }
```