# Create Login Window in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I was watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcmmCcMs8yU . It basically teaches me how to create my own login page using SQL Server.

So after following exactly what he did, when I click the submit button I have an error highlighting sda.Fill(dt);. I am pretty new to SQL Server, please advise!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're glad you're here. This is not a good question for our site. Have a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that will give you an idea of the kind of questions that are asked here. A big problem with your question is that it hinges on an external link that may or may not be there in the future. Also, you don't show us any of your code. If you can copy and paste the relevant piece of your code into your question, rather than asking us to watch a video, you will likely get better answers.

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for the replys i am having the exact same problems as this guy. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148583/c-sharp-login-page-sql-server-sda-filldt-error

I cant add images because my score is too low at the moment

Comment: Please open the link the images are on there but no solutions, i really need help. Hope you can help

Comment: Please post the code that populates your adapter, also please copy and paste the text shown in your exception.

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Ergo\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Table where USERNAME ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and PASSWORD ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")

Comment: {


                this.Hide();

                Main ss = new Main();
                ss.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Check Username and Password");
            }
        }

Comment: Please don't post your code into the comments; edit your question and add the code there. That way you can format the code so that it is readable. Code in comments is not nice to look at.