# Want to change a variable into * in c#

Tags: c#

I have a `string` called `password` which my user can define with whatever, `kim123` is an example.

So later in the code I want to say something like: `"You have entered (password but using asterisks) as your password."`

If you are still unclear by what I mean, I basically want to turn the password he/she chose into stars:

```
password = hey123

"You have entered ****** as your password"
```

Comment: You don't say what UI Framework you are using.  If you are using [tag:winforms], are you looking for [How to set a text box for inputing password in winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2555984)  If [tag:wpf] then maybe [How can I make a TextBox be a “password box” and display stars when using MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1119605)?  But you should never, ever **save** an unhashed copy of a user's password, see e.g. [How to securely save username/password (local)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12657792) or [C# - Securely storing a password locally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16957492).

Comment: If you are using asterisks to be more secure, displaying an accurate length of what the password is goes against that.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!

Comment: I'm using C#, I missed that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you generate so like

```
string pass = new String('*', password.Length); //will generate * as big as length of pasword
Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0} as your password", pass);
```

Comment: like: string password = "hello123";    string pass = new password('*', password.Length); ?

Comment: @JacksonMacDislike NO, like my answear ... try the posted code and it would work

Comment: Yeah I figured it out myself actually

Comment: @JacksonMacDislike Why create the variable `password`, you don't even use it?